# How I render a file to an an html line by line using jinja2

Tags: python, linux, web, mozilla, jinja2

I have file contains 100s of lines. I set all initializations of jinja2. I can able to render the file to my browser, but the problem is that it is not formated.(ie lines ar not come one by one).

So I want to render the file in formated way(ie is line by line in browser) using jinja2. What are the editing I need to done in my html file and python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `"<br/>"` to the end of the line so that a browser would do a line break?

Is that what you're aksing?

[edit]

read lines to an object in python:

```
lines = open("myfile.txt")
for line in lines:
    print line.rstrip() //rstrip removes whitespaces at the end
lines.close()
```

a template for jinja2 printing line by line from lines

```
<title>{% filename %}</title>
<body>
{% for line in lines %}
  {{ line }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Comment: Thak you for the replay...That I know but I want to render a file using python and jinja2 to my browser

Comment: is <title>{% filename %}</title> is must ?

Comment: no it's not, just to display the filename in the browsers header if you want.. if you don't need it just leave it, but a simple `filename = "myfile.txt"` in python would add that info to the output too

Comment: Is It possible to render a list (containing lines) and that lines are printed using the jinja code    <body>
{% for line in lines %}
  {{ line }}<br/>
{% endfor %}
</body>